# (Javascript) List of "navigator.appName" values for all browsers?

Tags: javascript, browser, browser-detection, navigator

What values are returned for `navigator.appName` values for all common browsers?

The `navigator.appName` value for Firefox is `Netscape`.

What values are returned for IE, Firefox, Google Chrome, Safari, Opera, Flock, etc.?

Comment: It's also "Netscape" for Chrome and Safari, probably other browsers too. So it's probably not the most useful property?

Comment: And Chromium (14) (perhaps obviously) on Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: What??? My god, why??? So, what the `navigator.appName` is using for? (or) just useless property?

Comment: It's a very old property, hailing from the Netscape days (hence the value often/always? being "Netscape"). I think some super old legacy code out there relies on it, so modern browsers tend to pretend to be Netscape to not break it.

Comment: Goshh!!! This is hell. And `.appCodeName` is not useful also. So, is there any single `Property` which i can use to identify the browser? @Matt, `super old legacy code` hmm? Haa ya.., kinda like that, and i luv that wordz .. lol

Comment: `navigator.userAgent` and `navigator.platform` are more likely to be useful. But even still, it's better to do feature detection over browser detection. Sometimes you do have to drop down to browser detection, but it should be a last resort.

Comment: `.platform` ? Please, do we really need it ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you trust the user agent, you can use this web site:
http://www.useragentstring.com/

It provides an API to analyse your current browser. It also has data on about every user agent you can imagine.

Answer (score 10):

Just found out IE11 preview has changed the value of navigator.appName:

before IE11, this value is:

```
"Microsoft Internet Explorer"
```

now with IE11 preview, this value has been changed to:

```
"Netscape"
```

not sure why MS did this, nor is this going to be permanent after the release of IE11

Comment: This is probably because [navigator.appName is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/appName) and browsers can return whatever they want.